# Count occurrences of array objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to create an array of counts based on the occurrences of the same object within a different array. So far, my code looks like this:

```
var dates = [];
$.each(items, function (i, item) {
    dates.push(item.date);
});
```

which returns:

```
['2013/03', '2013/03', '2012/01', '2012/11', '2012/09', '2012/09', '2012/09']
```

After that, I'd like to end up with an array that looks like this:

```
[2,1,1,3]
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a key/value counting approach where the date is the key and the value is the number of times it appears like so:

```
var counters = {};
$.each(dates, function(i, date) {
   counters[date] = counters[date] ? counters[date] + 1 : 1;
});
```

This approach assumes the dates will all be following identical formats of course.

**Edit:**

http://jsfiddle.net/wMR9x/2/

Then you can loop over it like so and simply join the results into another array:

```
var finalCounts = [];
var i = 0;
for(var key in counters)
    finalCounts[i++] = counters[key];
```

Comment: Shouldn't `counters` be an object, not an array.  The result of this operation will not be what the OP asked for.  It will not be `[2,1,1,3]` as those are actual array entries with indexes of `0`, `1`, `2`, etc...

Comment: @jfriend00 `counters` could be declared as an object but it doesn't really change much since an array is an object under the hood and I'm not calling `counters.length` which would return zero length but I'll change it for clarity. =D Furthermore, you would be correct in saying that `counters` wouldn't have the format the OP is after but if you take a look at `finalCounts`, that variable will contain `[2,1,1,3]` just as the OP requested as demonstrated in the jsfiddle provided.

Comment: Your version of `finalCounts` is not in any particular guaranteed order.  as iterating keys in an object has no guaranteed order.  The reason I went to so much more trouble in my answer was to guarantee the order of the output array to match the order the keys were encountered in the original data.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dates=['2013/03', '2013/03', '2012/01', '2012/11', '2012/09', '2012/09', '2012/09'];
var count={};
var count_array=[];
for (i in dates){
    count[dates[i]] =count[dates[i]]?count[dates[i]]+1:1;
}

for (i in count){
   count_array.push(count[i]);
}
console.log(count_array);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UKDUp/)

Answer (score 1):

Try the `countBy` function in underscore.js:

```
_.countBy(dates,_.identity);
```

That will return an object of the form

```
{'2013/03':2, ...}
```

If you want to retrieve just the counts from that object, use the `_.values` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var src = ['2013/03', '2013/03', '2012/01', '2012/11', '2012/09', '2012/09', '2012/09'];

var cnts = [];
for(var i = 0; i < src.length; i++){
    var val = src[i];
    var count = 1;
    while( val == src[i + 1]){
        count++;
        i++;
    }
    cnts.push(count)
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pk7rY/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can count the recurring values efficiently by using a map to keep track of the values you've already seen like this:

```
var data = ['2013/03', '2013/03', '2012/01', '2012/11', '2012/09', '2012/09', '2012/09'];

var map = {};
var sequence = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var item = data[i];
    if (map[item]) {
        map[item]++;
    } else {
        map[item] = 1;
        sequence.push(item);
    }
}

var output = [];
for (i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {
    output.push(map[sequence[i]]);
}

// output contains [2,1,1,3]
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/rQ7KB/

Answer (score 0):

You can use **push** method of the javascript array to achieve this

```
var arr = ['2013/03', '2013/03', '2012/01', '2012/11', '2012/09', '2012/09', '2012/09'];
var x = [],y = [], prev;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] !== prev) {
        x.push(arr[i]);
        y.push(1);
    } else {
        y[y.length - 1]++;
    }
    prev = arr[i];
}
console.log(y);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FNxtb/1/)