# Count occurrences of date based on hour in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, datetime

I have the following method -

```
// Push the date values into dateArray
var dateArray = [];

    $.each(dateHtml, function (i, el) {
                dateArray.push(htmlDateValue);
        }
    });
```

Then sort by earliest date -

```
// sort array to have earliest date first
    dateArray.sort(function (a, b) {
        return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
    });
```

Leaving me with for example -

```
dateArray = 
["02/10/2015 00:00:07", 
"02/10/2015 00:00:08", 
"02/10/2015 01:00:03",
"02/10/2015 01:00:05",
"02/10/2015 02:00:14",
"03/10/2015 07:00:37"];
```

I have created `var arrOfCounts = [];` which I want to fill with count values of each **hour** that exists in each **day**.

So for instance in the aforementioned array the result should be -

```
arrOfCounts  = 
[2,  // 2 instances of values within the hour of 00:00:00 on the 02/10/2015
 2,  // 2 instances of values within the hour of 01:00:00 on the 02/10/2015
 1,  // 1 instances of values within the hour of 02:00:00 on the 02/10/2015
 1]; // 1 instances of values within the hour of 07:00:00 on the 03/10/2015
```

So I have started to loop of each value in `dateArray` -

```
$.each(dateArray, function (i, el) {

                    // Here I have to establish the value of count
                    arrOfCounts.push(count);
            }
        });
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Without a doubt, start with a decent library that handles dates/times well! [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) is usually popular

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292349/count-occurrences-of-array-objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a custom object with the keys representing the dates and hours

```js
var dates = ["02/10/2015 00:00:07",
  "02/10/2015 00:00:08",
  "02/10/2015 01:00:03",
  "02/10/2015 01:00:05",
  "02/10/2015 02:00:14",
  "03/10/2015 07:00:37"
];
var counts = {};

dates.forEach(function(date) {
  var dateS = date.split(' ')[0];
  var hour = new Date(date).getHours();

  if (typeof counts[dateS] == 'undefined') {
    counts[dateS] = {};
  }

  if (typeof counts[dateS][hour] == 'undefined') {
    counts[dateS][hour] = 0;
  }

  counts[dateS][hour] += 1;
});

console.log(counts);
```

Comment: nailed it... until you try it on a browser where the constructor for a javascript date does not accept that format. Cant tell if you're US or UK format but whichever try swapping your browser to the other and use a date which does not look right in the other (eg, `24/12/2015`or `12/24/2015`)

Answer (score 0):

> So for instance in the aforementioned array the result should be -
>
> ```
> arrOfCounts  = 
> [2,  // 2 instances of values within the hour of 00:00:00 on the 02/10/2015
>  2,  // 2 instances of values within the hour of 01:00:00 on the 02/10/2015
>  1,  // 1 instances of values within the hour of 02:00:00 on the 02/10/2015
>  1]; // 1 instances of values within the hour of 07:00:00 on the 03/10/2015
> ```

Try utilizing `Array.prototype.map()` , `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/\d+:\d+/`, `Array.prototype.filter()`

```js
var dateArray = ["02/10/2015 00:00:07"
                 , "02/10/2015 00:00:08"
                 , "02/10/2015 01:00:03"
                 , "02/10/2015 01:00:05"
                 , "02/10/2015 02:00:14"
                 , "03/10/2015 07:00:37"
                ];

var arrOfCounts = dateArray.map(function(val) {
                    return val.match(/\d+:\d+/)[0]
                  })
                  .map(function(count, i, array) {
                    return count !== array[i + 1] 
                           ? array.toString()
                             .match(new RegExp(count, "g")).length 
                           : null
                  })
                  .filter(Boolean);
console.log(arrOfCounts)
```